# python elabftw requests.post()

Tags: python, tags

maybe someone knows about the labbook elabftw.
I am trying a simple request via python.

I tried this:

```
import os
import requests
import json

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

#########################
#         CONFIG        #
#########################

url = "http://localhost:8890/api/v2/experiments".format(host=host)
API_KEY = 'a2cmykeyc19be8'


headers = {'Authorization' : API_KEY}

data = {'title': 'test versuch','body':'test'}

response = requests.post(url,headers=headers, verify=False)

print(response)
```

And get : <Response [404]>

I hope for this result:

{'_date': '2023-08-30',
'body': ' test ',
'body_html': ' test ',
'canread': '{"base": 30, "teams": [], "users": [], "teamgroups": []}',
'canwrite': '{"base": 30, "teams": [], "users": [], "teamgroups": []}',
'category': 'Running',
'category_id': 61,
'color': '29AEB9',
'comments': [],
'content_type': 1,
'created_at': '2023-09-19 15:58:26',
'elabid': '20a10988eb20af0ee',
'events_id': None,
'events_item_id': None,
'firstname': '',
'fullname': '',
'has_attachement': None,
'has_comment': 0,
'id': 407,
'is_bound': None,
'lastchangeby': 29,
'lastname': '',
'links': None,
'locked': 0,
'lockedby': None,
'lockedwhen': None,
'metadata': None,
'modified_at': '2023-09-21 12:46:18',
'next_step': None,
'orcid': None,
'page': 'experiments',
'rating': 0,
'recent_comment': None,
'sharelink': 'https://elabftw.ptb.de/experiments.php?mode=view&id=407',
'state': 1,
'steps': [],
'tags': 'TLV|FM1|7.5-1V-23-37',
'tags_id': '95,97,163',
'timestamped': 0,
'timestamped_at': None,
'timestampedby': None,
'title': ' test versuch',
'type': 'experiments',
'up_item_id': None,
'uploads': [],
'userid': 29}

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the official documentation here: https://doc.elabftw.net/api/v2/#/Experiments/read-experiments

- you should use `GET`, not `POST`
- use `q=` parameter to query the experiments

```py
import requests

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

#########################
#         CONFIG        #
#########################

url = "http://localhost:8890/api/v2/experiments".format(host=host)
API_KEY = "a2cmykeyc19be8"


headers = {"Authorization": API_KEY}

params = {"q": "test versuch"}

# 1. remove verify=False, you're connecting to http://, not https://
# 2. to get result you wanted, use .get(), not .post()
# 3  according to the documentation, use q= parameter
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending any data with your request. If the API expects you to send data (like the title and body of the experiment), you should include it in your request. Here's how you can do it:

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, verify=False)
```

In this code, json=data sends the data dictionary as a JSON body with the request. May be this will fix the problem